# How to search text excluding html tags but return the corresponding html

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I have a few webpages that I'm familiar with some content of but not really the structure of the page itself such that webpages could be in the following form
Page 1

```
<strong> Some text</strong> I'm interested in <p> searching </p>
```

Page 2

```
<b> Some text I'm interested in </b> searching
```

Page 3

```
<div><p> Some text I'm interested in searching and this is some other text</p></div>
```

Is it possible without writing a tricky regex, to search through the page and look for the substring, and then also get the enclosing html as well?
Right now I'm simply extracting the text and searching with the substring but I would additionally want to return the html. Would there be a way using `Beautifulsoup` to achieve this?

```
html = urllib.request.urlopen('path').read().decode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
text = soup.get_text()
result = re.search(text, "Some text I'm interested in searching", re.I)
```

So the output from Page 1, I can extract (as shown above)

```
<strong> Some text</strong> I'm interested in <p> searching </p>
```

and so on..

Answer (score 0):

You can try search with `regex` and `beautifulsoup`:

```
import bs4
import re

html = """<strong> Some text</strong> I'm interested in <p> searching </p>
<b> Some text I'm interested in </b> searching
<div><p> Some text I'm interested in searching and this is some other text</p></div>"""

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
soup.find(text=re.compile("Some text I'm interested in searching")).parent
```

Output

```
<p> Some text I'm interested in searching and this is some other text</p>
```

Comment: Hi, I have made edit to the ques, basically these are different pages. I'd want to extract all three of these cases.